# Facebook Authentication PHP & AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, facebook

I have a website that first uses the Facebook Javascript API to log a user in. However, when a user sends an xmlhttp request to one of my PHP scripts I would like to check again to see if that user is logged in via PHP (for securities sake).

I had a working system but after a site makeover there seems to be a bug. When I echo $html in the facebook.php script I get this error: `{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException"}}`.

```
/* request.js */
var postData = "id=" + id;

sendRequest('assets/php/believe.php',function(req) {
  console.log(req.responseText);
},postData);

/* believe.php */
<?php
include("facebook.php");
$id = intval($_POST["id"]);

if($id == '') {
  //Stuff
} else {
  if($cookie) { 
    echo "hey";
  }
}
?>

/* facebook.php */
<?php
define('YOUR_APP_ID', 'xxxxxx');
define('YOUR_APP_SECRET', 'xxxxxxxxxxxx');

function curl_get_contents($url){
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    
  $html = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);
  echo "$html"; 
  return $html;
}

function get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $app_secret){
  $args = array();
  parse_str(trim($_COOKIE['fbs_' . $app_id], '\\"'), $args);
  ksort($args);
  $payload = '';
  foreach ($args as $key => $value){
    if ($key != 'sig'){
      $payload .= $key . '=' . $value;
    }
  }
  if (md5($payload . $app_secret) != $args['sig']){
    return null;
  }
  return $args;
}

$cookie = get_facebook_cookie(YOUR_APP_ID, YOUR_APP_SECRET);

$user = json_decode(curl_get_contents(
    'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' .
    $cookie['access_token']));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is fine. User access token is expired. If user renews it, the code will work. Make sure you have a valid token in the cookie